# Sum of multiple columns using jooq and join with another table

Tags: mysql, jooq

I have scenario where I have to find the sum of multiple columns from table2 and I have the value in where clause from another table1.

I wrote mySql query for the same as follow. I need to write it in the jooq.

```
select (sum(t2.column1)+sum(t2.column2)+sum(t2.column3)) as total_amount 
from db.table1 t1, db.table2 t2 
where t1.column1 = ‘value1’ and t1.column2 = t2.column4;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, all functions are available from [`org.jooq.impl.DSL`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html) by the same name, and all operators are available from [`org.jooq.Field`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html) by a name that reflects the way the operator is pronounced. In your case, use:

- [`DSL.sum(Field)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#sum-org.jooq.Field-)
- [`Field.plus(Field)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#plus-org.jooq.Field-)

Specifically, assuming this static import:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

Write:

```java
Table1 t1 = TABLE1.as("t1");
Table2 t2 = TABLE2.as("t2");
ctx.select(sum(t2.COLUMN1).plus(sum(t2.COLUMN2)).plus(t2.COLUMN3)).as("total_amount"))
   .from(t1, t2)
   .where(t1.COLUMN1.eq("value1"))
   .and(t1.COLUMN2.eq(t2.COLUMN4))
   .fetch();
```